# double free or corruption in data structures

Tags: c++

I have code below, where I implement a queue of heaps.

```
Queue<Heap<struct infoNode>, SIZE> queue;     
for(int c = 0 ; c < SIZE; c++)
{    
     Heap<struct infoNode> h;
     queue.enqueue(h, 0);
}
```

In heap, I have overloaded the copy constructor like this:

```
template <typename T>
Heap<T>::Heap(const Heap<T> &h)
{
        cout << "this " << this << " h " << &h << endl;
        capVect = h.capVect;
        if(values) delete [] values;
        values = new T[capVect];
        dimVect = h.dimVect;
        for(int i = 0; i < dimVect; i++)
            values[i] = h.values[i];
}
```

When I make `queue.enqueue(h, 0)`, I get double free or corruption. I don't understand why I see the same addresses here for this and the heap to be copied.

```
this 0x7ffcbc2771a0 h 0x7ffcbc277190
this 0x7ffcbc2771a0 h 0x7ffcbc277190
*** Error in `./comp': double free or corruption (top): 0x00000000017f0690 ***
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you show more of the `Heap`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `if(values) delete [] values;` should not be done in a constructor.

Comment: http://valgrind.org/

Comment: why not doing if(values) delete [] values in constructor?

Comment: @georgiana_e Please see mine and the other answer for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the copy constructor you have

```
if(values) delete [] values;
```

Since we are in a copy constructor none of the members have been initialized unless you specify them in the member initializer list.  If not they are either default constructed if they are default constructable or left in a indeterminate state if they are not.  Since `value` is a pointer its state is indeterminate which means evaluating it and deleting it is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a copy-constructor is just a constructor like the default constructor. When the copy-constructor is called the object is not initialize.

That means that member variables like `value` (which I *assume* is a member variable) are not initialized, and its value will be *indeterminate*. When you use it you will have *undefined behavior*.